How to write a trill from a 32nd notes
I need to turn this 32nd note trill on beat 3 into something simpler with a trill ornament
What would be the best way to write it?

What you have is clear. Trill signs can be ambiguous in relation to how many notes there are and whether to start on the upper or lower note. If you absolutely must have a trill or mordent sign and you want it played as you have written, match it to a footnote with the thing written out in full.

You should consider if: 1. you actually want it as an ornament or as a measured figure; 2. how much liberty you want to give to the player and their taste (or even technical capabilities). If you want it exactly like you've written, without any possibility of doubt or performer choice, keep it as it is in its extended form. Always remember that music (and written music especially) always has some level of freedom: ornaments are a clear hint that you want something "conceptually based to", but also possibly open to some level of interpretation.

I’d opt for this:

But keep in mind that an ornament is not exactly equivalent to the notated version. For one thing it has more ambiguity (how fast to trill?), but it also implies that the ornament is not part of the musical line, but added to the line. In your case I’d say spelling this as trill makes a lot of sense. But suppose you’d notate Beethoven’s WoO 59 like this:

While this would somehow work out it is not reasonable, as here the figure is clearly integral part of the musical line, not an ornamentation.
If you wish to use ornaments and want them to be played in a very specific way you need to be precise about it and explain or annotate what you want. You could for example do something like

or, if you use many trills to be performed the same way, something like


Thank you. as a composer I don't want peformers to have such freedom regarding trills. How many alterations directly impacts the voice leading and in my case, it needs to be played with the last note of the trill leading to the C of the next 16th note.. Should the performer start on the higher note, they would have a D leading to a D... that sounds poor. I see trills as a shorthand not as an artistic freedom given to performers. In other words, instead of writing so many 32nd notes a trill seems neater but which alteration to use makes a difference. Is it wrong to see trills this way?

@armani Starting note is not much of a problem, as there are clear conventions (baroque music → trill from the upper note, else → trill from lower note). As I said, trills are ornaments and ornaments do imply artistic freedom. If you want to be specific, then notate it. You can of course use a trill and annotate how exactly it is supposed to be played. It does not matter if you see trills just as shorthands. What matters is notational and interpretational practice. But then I ask you: Why do you want to use trills in the first place? They are not a tool fit for the job you intend it for.

@armani And annotating trills is possible, but it will add an element of confusion. So then you need to make sure that your score remains clear to understand.

@armani I’ve added some examples of how you can annotated the trills.

Thank you, great answer

@armani Any performer worth their salt will have voice leading in mind and execute the trill so it fits the music. There shouldn't be any need to nitpick in this instance, they'll figure it out.
